# How to encode for "Entity 'igrave' not defined" error in XML feed?

Tags: php, xml, entity

I'm building a feed from an url, so I take all the html content (with "file_get_contents" php function). Then I do some cuts to the content and take out what I need.

It seems I've a problem with the accented vocals. In fact XML page return me this error:
"Entity 'igrave' not defined", where the html is "
    ì
" (the html code for "ì").
The same is for ograve...

So, have I to proceed all the contents with str_replace or there is an encode/decoding function to resolve every possible problems?

Answer (score 0):

Xml does not know the named entities from (X)HTML. If you get this error the feed is invalid and should be fixed.

As a workaround, you can get the translation table from PHP and use it with str_replace().

```
function decodeNamedEntities($string) {
  static $entities = NULL;
  if (NULL === $entities) {
    $entities = array_flip(
      array_diff(
        get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8'),
        get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8')
      )
    );
  }
  return str_replace(array_keys($entities), $entities, $string);
}

var_dump(decodeNamedEntities('<b>&lt;&auml;hhh/gt;</b>'));
```

Output:

```
string(20) "<b>&lt;ähhh/gt;</b>"
```